# how to loop the program

Tags: javascript, jquery

the below code works for one time only.I dont know how to execute for continuos time.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".checkboxes").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".Select").click(function () {
            jQuery(this).next(".checkboxes").slideToggle(500);
            if ($(".select").text() == "+") {
                alert('hi');
                $(".select").html() == "-"
            }
            else {
                $(".select").text() == "+";
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your Html also.

Comment: ok i will add my htmlcode

Comment: what error you are getting ? ....  'imageup ' is not defined ?

Comment: i am not getting any error.the image is not replacing

Comment: Well what's the variable `imageup`?

Comment: i updated my code.please take a look

Comment: What type of element is .select ? And where is the image? Can't you show the HTML code?

Comment: "*ok i will add my htmlcode*" - when, because without it this question seems unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Considering ".imgContainer" is an `<img>` tag :

```
   $(function () {
            $(".checkboxes").hide();
            //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
            $(".select").click(function () {
                $(this).next(".checkboxes").slideToggle(500);
                if ($(".select").text() == "+")
                    $(".imgContainer").attr("src", "/images/logo1.png");
                else
                    $(".imgContainer").attr("src", "/images/logo2.png");
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: i want to replace the image instead of opertor

Comment: Post edited. I'm not really sure about what you want and/or need though. You want the image to change when the user clicks on ".Select", right ?